# emulate typing and keypresses in terminal

Tags: bash, scripts

is there a way to using a script, emulate actually typing a command and pressing enter?

like emulating typing ls then enter?

`me@mymachine $ ls`

I know this is possible in AppleScript, but is there a way in bash / shell?

Comment: What's the use case here? Do you want to use this from the command line or from a GUI, or...? The usual way would be to just run a script, so there must be something that can't be done that way?

Comment: I want to automate a challenge bot; where you have to type it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for app called `xdotool`.  Basically, you want this

```
xdotool type ls ; xdotool key Return
```

It is not installed by default so use `sudo apt-get install xdotool` to obtain it